# Python pandas multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, filter, multiple-conditions

Sorry, I apologise now, just started learning Python and trying to get something working.

Ok dataset is

```
Buy, typeid, volume, issued, duration, Volume Entered,Minimum Volume, range, price, locationid, locationname

SELL    20  2076541 2015-09-12T06:31:13 90  2076541 1   region  331.21  60008494    Amarr

SELL    20  194642  2015-09-07T19:36:49 90  194642  1   region  300 60008494    Amarr

SELL    20  2320    2015-09-13T07:48:54 3   2320    1   region  211 60008491    Irnin
```

I would like to filter for a specific location either by name or ID, doesn't bother me, then to pick the minimum price for that location. Preferably to hardcode it in, since I only have a few locations I'm interested. e.g locationid = 60008494.

I see you can do two conditions on one line, but I don't see how to apply it.
So I'm trying to nest it.
Doesn't have to be pandas, just seems the first thing I found that did one part of what I required.

The code I've gotten so far is, and only does the minimum part of what I'm looking to achieve.

```
data = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')
length = len(data['typeid'].unique())
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Buy', 'typeid', 'volume','duration','volumeE','Minimum','range','price','locationid','locationname'))
for i in range(0,length):
        name_filter = data[data['typeid'] == data['typeid'].unique()[i]]
        price_min_filter = name_filter[name_filter['price'] == name_filter['price'].min() ]  
        res = res.append(price_min_filter, ignore_index=True) 
        i=i+1
        res.to_csv('format.csv') # writes output to csv
print "Complete"
```

UPDATED.
Ok so, the latest part, seems like the following code is the direction I should be going in. If I could have s=typeid, locationid and price, thats perfect. So I've written what I want to do, whats the correct syntax to get that in python? Sorry I'm used to Excel and SQL.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')
df[df['locationid'] ==60008494]
s= df.groupby(['typeid'])['price'].min()
s.to_csv('format.csv')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its hard for us to tell what is going wrong here, and what you'd expect. Perhaps you could give us a bit more information, specifically: what is the output that you would expect from your code? What are you getting instead? Have you tried each of the conditions on their own to make sure that they are working by themselves before combining? Did they achieve the results you'd expect? Show us the results? Note: please edit your question and add this information there - don't put it in the comments as code formatting is awful.

Comment: Ok, well there are thousands of typeid's and thousands of locations. Just wanted to be able to filter for specific locations and for each typeid, to produce the minimum price.

Main issue I'm having is divining the right formula and putting it into a state where I can use the products for the following conditions? So I'm ending up importing from a csv, calculating, then exporting to a csv, so I can use the results.
So the process is basically, I only want location 60008494, group by, then finding the minimum price value for each typeid, for that one location.
Hope that is clearer.

Comment: Well, you don't need to give us your full database... just some example data and example output that you'd expect. You can pretend that there are only 4-5 rows in your database, and use that as a representative sample.

Comment: We can't figure out the right formula for you - if you don't give us an accurate and precise definition of what you need. sample inputs/outputs gives us that, which is why I asked. It would help us to help you if you read this article and adapted your question to fit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If what you really want is -

> I would like to filter for a specific location either by name or ID, doesn't bother me, then to pick the minimum price for that location. Preferably to hardcode it in, since I only have a few locations I'm interested. e.g locationid = 60008494.

You can simply filter the df on the `locationid` first and then use `['price'].min()`. Example -

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = """Buy,typeid,volume,issued,duration,Volume Entered,Minimum Volume,range,price,locationid,locationname
   ...: SELL,20,2076541,2015-09-12T06:31:13,90,2076541,1,region,331.21,60008494,Amarr
   ...: SELL,20,194642,2015-09-07T19:36:49,90,194642,1,region,300,60008494,Amarr
   ...: SELL,20,2320,2015-09-13T07:48:54,3,2320,1,region,211,60008491,Irnin"""

In [3]: import io

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
    Buy  typeid   volume               issued  duration  Volume Entered  \
0  SELL      20  2076541  2015-09-12T06:31:13        90         2076541
1  SELL      20   194642  2015-09-07T19:36:49        90          194642
2  SELL      20     2320  2015-09-13T07:48:54         3            2320

   Minimum Volume   range   price  locationid locationname
0               1  region  331.21    60008494        Amarr
1               1  region  300.00    60008494        Amarr
2               1  region  211.00    60008491        Irnin

In [8]: df[df['locationid']==60008494]['price'].min()
Out[8]: 300.0
```

If you want to do it for all the locationids', then as said in the other answer you can use `DataFrame.groupby` for that and then take the `['price']` column for the group you want and use `.min()`. Example -

```
data = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')
data.groupby(['locationid'])['price'].min()
```

Demo -

```
In [9]: df.groupby(['locationid'])['price'].min()
Out[9]:
locationid
60008491    211
60008494    300
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

---

For getting the complete row which has minimum values in the corresponding groups, you can use `idxmin()` to get the index for the minimum value and then pass it to `df.loc` to get those rows. Example -

```
In [9]: df.loc[df.groupby(['locationid'])['price'].idxmin()]
Out[9]:
    Buy  typeid  volume               issued  duration  Volume Entered  \
2  SELL      20    2320  2015-09-13T07:48:54         3            2320
1  SELL      20  194642  2015-09-07T19:36:49        90          194642

   Minimum Volume   range  price  locationid locationname
2               1  region    211    60008491        Irnin
1               1  region    300    60008494        Amarr
```

Comment: where "locationid"==60008494

s= data.groupby(['typeid'])['price'].min()

The second line is perfect, but how do you implement the first stage, where location id can be specified for the group by to apply to the subset?

Comment: If you want the min only for a specific locationid use the first method - `data[data['locationid']==60008494]['price'].min()`

Comment: Okay, I'm getting there.
For the s= part, how would you add locationid, so then I can export to csv those three columns?

Comment: You can get the whole row (with all columns) using the last method - `idxmin()` one, then take the required columns from it. Example - `data.loc[data[data['locationid']==60008494]['price'].idxmin()]` . Then take the required columns

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you really won't need to do much more than a [`DataFrame.Groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).  As an example, you can group the dataframe by the `locationname`, then select the `price` column from the resulting groupby object, then use the `min()` method to output the minimum value for each group:

```
data.groupby('locationname')['price'].min()
```

which will give you the minimum value of `price` for each group.  So it will look something like:

```
locationname
Amarr    300
Irnin    211
Name: price, dtype: float64
```